# How to change colors repeatedly with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought that this should work:

```js
$("#manual").css("color","red").fadeIn(400).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150).css("color","black");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="manual">
      some text here
    </div>
```

I'm expecting it to be red and then black but it isn't doing that, why?

Comment: is there any error returning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by 'doesn't work' you mean that the text turns black immediately, that's because `css()` doesn't operate on the `fx` queue as the `fadeX()` functions do. To fix this, change the text colour in the callback of the last `fade` call:

```js
$("#manual").css("color", "red").fadeIn(400)
  .fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150)
  .fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150, function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="manual">
  some text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SetInterval function for it:

```
  var v=['red','green','yellow','blue'];
  var x=0;
  setInterval(
    function(){
       $("#manual").css("color",v[x]); x++;
    }, 
    3000
    );
```